# How to connect snap application to screen share

Tags: 20.04, permissions, snap

I want to allow a snap application to share my screen but can't find out how to do this.
I have one application which is able to do so and one in which I can't seem to be able to do this...
Here is the output of `snap connections discord` (this one does work)

```
Interface                 Plug                            Slot                             Notes
browser-support           discord:browser-support         :browser-support                 -
camera                    discord:camera                  :camera                          -
content[gnome-3-28-1804]  discord:gnome-3-28-1804         gnome-3-28-1804:gnome-3-28-1804  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     discord:gtk-3-themes            gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      discord:icon-themes             gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     discord:sound-themes            gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
desktop                   discord:desktop                 :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            discord:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 discord:gsettings               :gsettings                       -
home                      discord:home                    :home                            -
mount-observe             discord:mount-observe           -                                -
network                   discord:network                 :network                         -
network-observe           discord:network-observe         -                                -
opengl                    discord:opengl                  :opengl                          -
process-control           discord:process-control         -                                -
pulseaudio                discord:pulseaudio              :pulseaudio                      -
removable-media           discord:removable-media         -                                -
screen-inhibit-control    discord:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control          -
system-observe            discord:system-observe          -                                -
unity7                    discord:unity7                  :unity7                          -
wayland                   discord:wayland                 :wayland                         -
x11                       discord:x11                     :x11                             -
```

And for comparison here is the output of the application which I can't seem to get to work (`snap connections rambox`)

```
Interface                 Plug                    Slot                             Notes
audio-playback            rambox:audio-playback   :audio-playback                  -
audio-record              rambox:audio-record     -                                -
browser-support           rambox:browser-support  :browser-support                 -
camera                    rambox:camera           :camera                          manual
content[gnome-3-28-1804]  rambox:gnome-3-28-1804  gnome-3-28-1804:gnome-3-28-1804  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     rambox:gtk-3-themes     gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      rambox:icon-themes      gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     rambox:sound-themes     gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
desktop                   rambox:desktop          :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            rambox:desktop-legacy   :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 rambox:gsettings        :gsettings                       -
home                      rambox:home             :home                            -
network                   rambox:network          :network                         -
opengl                    rambox:opengl           :opengl                          -
pulseaudio                rambox:pulseaudio       :pulseaudio                      -
removable-media           rambox:removable-media  -                                -
unity7                    rambox:unity7           :unity7                          -
wayland                   rambox:wayland          :wayland                         -
x11                       rambox:x11              :x11                             -
```

I have looked at how to fix it and thought that maybe screencast-legacy would be the slot that I'd need, but I'm unsure of the plug I'd use...